# Insert statement with a where clause c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to insert details into a table depending on value from a cookie, . here is the code

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = "insert into Details (Employees, Performance, TotalPerformance, Attitude, TotalAttitude) values(@employees, @performance ,@totalPerformance, attitude, totalAttitude)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employees", Request.QueryString["employees"]);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@performance", totalPer.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPerformance", totalPercent.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attitude", totalAtt.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalattitude", totalPercent.ToString());



        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This works fine but in the string insert query line I want to add in a where clause, where it will insert the values into a certain row if the value for column "name" in said row  matches a cookie . I don't know the proper syntax 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177523.aspx) statement, not an `INSERT` statement, since you are going to modify the existing record.

```
using (
    SqlConnection conn =
        new SqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    string updateQuery =
        @"UPDATE Details 
        SET Employees = @employeee, 
        Performance = @performance , 
        TotalPerformance = @totalPerformance,
        Attitude = @attitude,
        TotalAttitude = @totalattitude
        WHERE yourField = @yourConditionValue";

    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employees", Request.QueryString["employees"]);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@performance", totalPer.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPerformance", totalPercent.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attitude", totalAtt.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalattitude", totalPercent.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourConditionValue", yourValue);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

+1, for using parameters in your question, one other thing, [enclose your `Command` and `Connection` object in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx) `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is sometimes referred to as an `UPSERT`.  It will `UPDATE` the record if it already exists, or `INSERT` if it doesn't.

SQL Server 2008 and newer have the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) keyword for this functionality.  Otherwise, I would write a stored procedure with an `IF` statement with the correct logic.